# What is the reference/name of this connector?

Tags: connector, terminal

I would like to know the name/reference of this connector:
[image: m.unit]

This is for 2.5mm² max wire
When you push the orange button, it unleash the wire

Thank you

Comment: spring terminal block

Comment: Cage clamp. See [Screw or push-in terminal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213996/is-a-screw-or-push-in-terminal-better-for-vibrating-environment/214019#214019).

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for this specific model. i have a bunch of different references but I need this one ;)

Comment: You seem to have your hands on the device, does it have a manual you can find, check the manual maybe the part number is in it. Otherwise contact the manufacturer.

Comment: That connector likely pulls off. Look for markings.

Comment: This is not mine and I can't contact the manufacturer
I will scroll famous electronic webshop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That connector type goes by various names: wire-trap, poke-home, push-in and so forth. It’s a solderless connector that’s popular for low-voltage field wiring of controls and security.

The type shown seems to be a 'euro block' connector style. Example: https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?1dmy&urile=wcm:path:/gben/web/main/products/subcategory_pages/Push-in_connection_P-15-02/868cc764-43df-41cb-9e7d-c2429d2efe8c

Not so sure how reliable they’d be for a motorcycle though, given vibration, weather, temperature concerns. Kind of a crappy design really. Pigtails with weather-tight connectors would be more suitable.