# KF188A screwless terminal

Tags: connector

I have a LED driver with following Push-in screw terminal (from the markings of the side)
[image]

Here is the technical [drawing](http://www.nb-kaifeng.com/upload/file/1612424424.pdf).
I am unable to figure out the mechanics.

How can I connect the cables?

Comment: You shove the bare wire end into the big bottom hole. You might need to shove a screw driver into the big bottom hole as you do this to hold the spring open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. [Wago cage-clamp terminals](http://www.wago.com/infomaterial/pdf/51184677.pdf).*

Some of the terminals require a 'just right' screwdriver to release the cage properly. (Some screw terminals require the right tool too.)

[image: Cage clamp and wire]

*Figure 2. Cage clamp and wire showing excellent contact area.*

(Photos used previously in my answer to [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213079/are-these-pin-connectors-a-standard-part-if-so-what-are-they-called/213086#213086).)

Comment: Good pictures. With a small screwdrivers I was able to push the clamp in the smaller upper hole forward to reveal the clamp in the bigger hole. Thanks