# How to describe the basic cabling used in industrial electrical panels?

Tags: cables, panel

How would the basic cabling in electrical panels be technically described (in order to make a purchase, for example?) Does it have a certain number of cores?

I'm talking about the kind of cabling you see going into the top ports of this terminal block:

[image: Terminal Block]

For example, would the cable linked [here](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/6XV1801-2A) be suitable to replace it?

The circuit overall is rated at 20 amps of three-phase, 230V power.

Comment: What voltages are on the wires and what currents might they be carrying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable you have linked to is a 4-core double-insulated cable. That's suitable for *outside* the panel.

[image]

*Figure 1. 0.75 mm<sup>2</sup> hookup and equipment wire. Image source: [RS](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/hookup-equipment-wire/7244241).*

Your panel is showing single-insulated panel hookup wire. This is multi-strand for flexibility. Strand packing is usually done in 1 (single-core), 7, 19 strands, etc. which gives the best packing without gaps.

Stranded cables work will all common terminals including screw clamp, cage clamp (below) and can be pin-crimped.

[image]

*Figure 2. [Wago cage-clamp terminals](http://www.wago.com/infomaterial/pdf/51184677.pdf).*

Some of the terminals require a 'just right' screwdriver to release the cage properly. (Some screw terminals require the right tool too.)

[image: Cage clamp and wire]

*Figure 3. Cage clamp and wire showing excellent contact area.*

For 20 A you should be considering 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> or 4 mm<sup>2</sup> hookup wire.

(Photos used previously in my answer to [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213079/are-these-pin-connectors-a-standard-part-if-so-what-are-they-called/213086#213086).)

Answer (score 2):

MTW (Machine Tool Wire) often rated for 600V. This is the more flexible type of wire used for control box wiring. It is not typically used for field wiring outside of the box, typically THHN is used for conduit pulls etc.